# How to clean up multiple Azure resources with single powershell command or script?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-cli2, powershell-az-module

I am trying to clean up the unused resources in my Azure subscription. there are about 80-90 resources in each subscriptions. It is possible to select and search one by one and delete them. Is there anyway to export the resource names and call a "az resource delete" or something similar to delete the resources that I need to remove?

I tried the following

1. First I set the account : az account set -s subscription_ID
2. Set the resource group : az configure --defaults group=testrg
3. I am running the command : az resource delete -n testvnet --resource-type "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks" but this is allowing me to delete only 1 resource at a time, I need to keep adding the names.

Can I pass multiple resource names in a single command or can I upload a CSV with resource names, resource types and then it deletes all resources that are there in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following PowerShell scripts:

```
# Delete all Virtual Network resources from resource groups
$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup
foreach ($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
 Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks | Remove-AzResource -Force
}
```

```
# Delete specific Virtual Networks resources from resource groups
$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup
$listOfVirtualNetworksNamesToBeRemoved = @('vnet1','vnet2','vnet3')
foreach ($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
 $virtualNetworks = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks
 $virtualNetworks | ForEach-Object {
  if($listOfVirtualNetworksNamesToBeRemoved -match $_) {
    Remove-AzResource -ResourceId $_.ResourceId -Force
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: I ran the above comment in Azure CLI, it deleted all the resources in my subscription under all RG's

I want to delete only select resources but there are over 80-90 resources that I need to delete. Do I have an option to specify the parameter in the script where I can mention the resource name or pass the list of resource names.

Comment: I updated my answer for two possible scenarios: 1. Deleting all Virtual Network resources from resource groups 2. Deleting specific Virtual Networks resources from resource groups